# Системная переменная PATH

Tags: python

В моем проекте на python имеются 2 директории (backend, kernel). При запуске главных файлов в директориях -  main.py из командной строки получается следующая ошибка:

```
from kernel.server import app
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kernel'
```

Чтобы избежать данных ошибок необходимо в системную переменную PATH добавить пути к каталогам.
Вопрос. Как это сделать правильно?

Comment: В переменную PATH нужно добавлять исполняемые файлы, чтобы их можно было запускать просто по имени, это в принципе не имеет прямого отношения к Python. Модули Python нужно добавлять в PYTHONPATH. Как правильно - как вам удобнее. Можно сделать эти папки частями одного пакета, тогда вообще не нужно будет в PYTHONPATH добавлять, просто использовать относительный импорт или абсолютный через имя общего пакета (типа `from project.kernel.serve import app`)

Comment: @insolor, Воспользовался вашим советом. Перенес две папки в одну общую, запускаю также исполняемые файлы из консоли и происходит все та же ошибка, но уже, что не видит модуля - общий папки. Может быть надо __init__.py файлы в папки добавить?

Comment: Нужно из папки снаружи пакета запускать, причем как модуль, а не одиночный файл, типа `python -m project.backend.main`